# Is there a specific word for burps/belching from alcohol?

Tags: single-word-requests

This might be a bit pedantic but just working on a translation at the moment and it got me wondering if there is any specific word for alcohol(ic) belching/burps?

Searching only gives results like:

- *burping and alcohol*
- *belching and alcohol*

In Chinese there is the word `酒嗝` which literally means `alcohol burp`.

Is there an equivalent in English?

I guess it would more likely be a beer burp more than anything else, as there isn't often belching from Wine or spirits.

Comment: The obvious portmanteau would be **beerp** (beer + burp). It’s not something I’ve ever thought of as a thing, really, but [beerp is actually on UrbanDictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beerp), so I’m not the first to think of it either, it would seem.

Comment: @Janus if this is about beer, then the burps are all about the carbonation and nothing to do with alcohol.

Comment: _Boozurp_ (portmanteau from _booze_ and _burp_).

Comment: Im getting whiplash from my burps

Comment: portmanteau from eructation and alcohol = err ... nothing.

Answer (score 1):

No, not that I can find in English. Google translates your word 酒嗝 to "wine burp" as well. In English, it is implied that a burp or belch is from food or drink and is usually specified before the word. Like, "that beer is making me burp", or "I am burping from that soda".